# How object hash works to remove duplicates in this scenario?

Tags: javascript

```js
function distinctUnion(arr, arr2) {
  let merged = [...arr, ...arr2];
  var result = [];
  var map = {}
  for (let i = 0; i < merged.length; i++) {
    if (!map.hasOwnProperty(merged[i])) {
      map[merged[i]] = true; // Line 3 --> if I remove this line, it prints duplicates
      console.log('map', JSON.stringify(map, 2, null));
      result.push(merged[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

let arr = [3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 10];
let arr2 = [11, 11, 11, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6];
console.log('unique ', JSON.stringify(distinctUnion(arr, arr2), 2, null));
```

All we are setting here is `map[merged[i]] = true;` for all keys in object

```
map {"3":true,"4":true,"5":true,"6":true,"8":true,"9":true,"10":true,"11":true}
```

then how `result.push(merged[i])` has only unique values?

I mean to say `merged[i]` inside loop should still have all array values including duplicates right?

I am not able to understand the link between `map[merged[i]] = true;` and `result.push(merged[i])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not set the property to anything, `map.hasOwnProperty(...)` will spuriously return false for the next time that value is encountered, thus allowing duplicates. You don't need to set it to true, as it is just used to indicate the presence of a key; any value is fine—even undefined!

```js
function distinctUnion(arr, arr2) {
  let merged = [...arr, ...arr2];
  var result = [];
  var map = {}
  for (let i = 0; i < merged.length; i++) {
    if (!map.hasOwnProperty(merged[i])) {
      map[merged[i]] = undefined;
      result.push(merged[i]);
    }
  }
  return result;
}

let arr = [3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 10];
let arr2 = [11, 11, 11, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6];
console.log('unique ', JSON.stringify(distinctUnion(arr, arr2), 2, null));
```

Comment: @kittu No problem.

Comment: Any idea how to print `return [3, 8, 9, 10, 11]` instead of what I tried? The output is supposed to be distinct union of arrays

Comment: @kittu You might want to ask a new question.

Comment: I will but I am not sure the expected return output is correct either in case of intersection or getting unique values

Answer (score 0):

To make your code works, you just need to replace **map[merged[i]] = true;** with **map[merged[i]] = undefined;**.

However, you can make your function more simplified as follows:

```js
function distinctUnion(arr, arr2) {
  let map = {};
  [...arr, ...arr2].forEach((x)=>{map[x] = x});
  
  return Object.values(map);;
}

let arr = [3, 4, 5, 6, 6, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 10];
let arr2 = [11, 11, 11, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6];

console.log('Unique ', distinctUnion(arr, arr2));
```